# What is a Michielsen chart and how should one use it?

Tags: orbital-mechanics, history, terminology, reference-request, ballistics

I've read about a Michielsen chart, but cannot currently find Kaplan's [1976 book](https://www.worldcat.org/title/modern-spacecraft-dynamics-control/oclc/2317997). What is this chart? Is it outdated nowadays?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From *Gerald R. Hintz, [Orbital Mechanics and Astrodynamics: Techniques and Tools for Space Missions](https://books.google.com/books?id=bewXBgAAQBAJ&pg=PA261&lpg=PA261&dq=space%20Michielsen%20chart&source=bl&ots=X61F7a7YMs&sig=p2lrZfjervsayQTloujdpcJ7CWo&hl=en&sa=X&ei=HzqNVZCOC8Lc-QGCqoGADw&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=space%20Michielsen%20chart&f=false)*, 2015:

> Michielsen devised a graphical display for all lunar transfer
> information, including passage effects, on a single plot. This chart
> is presented in Fig. 7.9 [missing from preview, see below] with an
> application to the Apollo 11 Mission. The $v_r$ axis is calibrated in
> km/s, but is directly related to transfer time. Thus, each value of
> $v_r$ associated with the transfer orbit corresponds to a unique value
> of transfer time. The two vertical lines marking the constant values
> of $v_\theta = \pm 0.19\text{ km/s}$ at $r_\text{M}$ are calibrated in
> days to reach $r_\text{M}$, i.e., the transfer time from Earth to the
> Moon. Transfers which have $v_\theta = + 0.19\text{ km/s}$ are direct
> and those with $v_\theta = - 0.19\text{ km/s}$ are retrograde.
>
> The Earth intercept zone connotes return to the Earth without any
> thrusting maneuvers.
>
> Note the Moon's velocity vector $v_M$. The magnitude
>
> #### $$v_{\theta_M} = v_c = \sqrt{\frac{\mu_⊕}{r_M}} = 1.02\text{ km/s}$$
>
> since the Moon is assumed to be in a circular orbit about the Earth.
> So the point $v_\theta \cong 1\text{ km/s}$, $v_r \cong 0$ is the
> orbital velocity of the Moon with respect to the Earth.
>
> A probe's approach $(v_\theta, v_r)$ is specified by the transfer
> trajectory. Hyperbolic passage of the Moon is handled in an analogous
> manner to that for planetary passage.
>
> As the spacecraft reaches $r_M$, the Earth's gravitational attraction
> is "turned off" (in the model). The deflection angle $\delta$ measures
> the turning of the spacecraft's velocity in the Moon-relative
> hyperbolic trajectory. A typical velocity vector diagram for lunar
> passage is shown in Fig. 7.10. Since the spacecraft passes in front of
> the Moon, the turn angle $\delta$ is taken clockwise and geocentric
> energy is decreased via a gravity assist (see Fig. 3.18 [missing from
> preview]). These vector triangles predict the probe's departure
> velocity $v^+$ from the Moon.

Instead of the missing Fig. 7.9 from the quote source, here's *Michielsen Chart for Lunar Encounter* from the *Marshall H. Kaplan, Modern Spacecraft Dynamics and Control* that you mention, taken from Robert Stengel's (Princeton University) [untitled lecture slides](http://www.princeton.edu/%7Estengel/MAE342Lecture9.pdf) (PDF, approved for educational use), page 7. Sharpened a bit for clarity but I do apologize for its quality, it's the best I could find:

> **Michielsen Chart for Lunar Encounter**
> *(Kaplan, Modern Spacecraft Dynamics and Control, 1976)*
>
> [image: Michielsen Chart for Lunar Encounter]
>
> - Orbital velocity of the Moon (wrt Earth), $v_\theta \sim 1\text{ km/s}$, $v_r \sim 0$
> - Probe's approach $v_\theta$, and $v_r$, specified by transfer trajectory
> - Probe's approach deflection angle, $\delta$, specified by Moon-relative hyperbolic trajectory
> - Vector triangles predict probe's departure velocity vector
> - Transfer time to Moon shown
> - “Earth intercept zone” connotes return to Earth without thrusting maneuver
> - Earth escape also possible